# Efficient approach to update the minute and hour hands in analog clock

Tags: android

I'm creating a widget for analog clock and i wanted to know what would be the efficient way of updating the minute and hour hands in UI apart from TimerTask and using AnalogClock xml tag

Comment: Here you can find a good example of UI update for an analog clock: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a good example of UI update for an analog clock: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

ps: Don't want to leave a question unanswered, so I transformed a comment in an answer.